# ASP.NET User Defined Wizard

Tags: asp.net, wizard, user-defined

I am starting a project in which the end user would like to create a wizard via our web application in order to drive users to specific pages within the application by answering a series of questions.

Has anyone had to do anything similar before?

Are there any open source or purchaseable products that I can implement or build off of to help?

Answer (score 0):

Christian I visualize that there are some generic pages that will be used to capture information from the user. These may have to be to turn on or off certain inputs or features. 
Based on the type of question your users will select the type of page they want in wizard, like multiple choice, subjective etc.

Then you will have to give user facility to select question they want to ask. Take question and type of page to be used for them and create wizard thing. The order of question will determine the order of page navigation.

Then you need to have your navigation framework that can take the wizard thing and guide end-user through all the steps.

You will also need common validation framework to decide if end-user should be allowed to move to next page.

This is very primitive but you can start thinking with this. Visiting polling and survey site to know how they create surveys this will help you to create user interface.